# Confidence Interval Formula of ci.se of pROC library (R)

Tags: r, proc-r-package

I have searched at the documentation of the library and I dont find what type of CI Formula uses the function ci.se for calculating the interval.
In this article https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Confidence_Intervals_for_One-Sample_Sensitivity_and_Specificity.pdf I see that there is at leats 5 formulas for calculating the CI of the sensitivity.
Anybody knows about this function? I need to know the type of formula because I'm using it on a research.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/blob/master/R/ci.se.R

Comment: I don't understand why you are offering a link to an SPSS/PASS documentation page when the issue is flagged [r]? This sounds like either a methods question or a request for references to outside sources, either of which should result in it being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithms are documented in [the help page of the `ci.se` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/ci.se) and in [Robin X *et al* 2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1471-2105-12-77).